# How to get the type of an EF dynamic proxy class without a class instance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, dynamic-proxy, gettype

Dynamic proxies have names like `ClassName_00394CF1F92740F13E3EDBE858B6D599DFAF87AA5A089245977F61A32C75AA22` where the POCO class was simply called `Classname`.

I know to can get the POCO type of an EF dynamic proxy instance with `ObjectContext.GetObjectType(instance.GetType())`, but is there an easier way to get the proxy type of a given EF class than this:

```
databaseContext.TableName.First().GetType();
```

As this requires there be an instance of the type in the table (usually the case, but this smells "wrong").

I am passing class types to a function (like below) so that certain parent/child drag & drop rules can be applied to TreeNodes (the object instances are referenced by Tag property of TreeNodes so have the dynamic type for any EF objects).

```
if (!AllowChildDrop(e.Node, e.TargetNode, e.DropPosition, typeof(Answer)), typeof(Question)))
```

So basically is there an easier way to get the dynamic type than this?

```
if (!AllowChildDrop(e.Node, e.TargetNode, e.DropPosition, context.Answer.First().GetType(), context.Question.First().GetType()))
```

Comment: This might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee835846(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to avoid creating an instance to discover the runtime `Type`.

You should use `DbSet.Create()` not `First()`

1. to avoid a potential trip to the database
2. the `First()` instance may not be a proxy (e.g. you added an entity earlier in the call chain)

see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679504%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) for more information

> [the] instance is not added or attached to the set. The instance returned will be a proxy if the underlying context is configured to create proxies and the entity type meets the requirements for creating a proxy.

Comment: +1: Thanks for that. I saw something similar using create after posting this question.